# Getting 'rosgraph resource not found' when trying to get turtlebot local_plan?

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, rosgraph, rospy, nav-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to get the `'geometry_msgs/Poses'` message from the `'/move_base/DWAPlannerROS/local_plan'` topic for the Kobuki Turtlebot. My current code is as follows: (This is an extremely minimal implementation where I am just accessing the value of the X position).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from nav_msgs.msg import Path

def callback(data):
    global xPos
    xPos = data.Pose.position.X;

def getPlan():
    rospy.init_node('plangetter', anonymous=False);

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        rospy.Subscriber('/move_base/DWAPlannerROS/local_plan', Path, callback);
        rospy.sleep(1);
        print "X is: " + xPos;

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        getPlan();
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

My questions are:

1. Why am I getting a `'rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: rosgraph'` error when running this code? I have checked my `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` and used `rospack find rosgraph` to confirm that ROS has access to the package. I have also made sure my PYTHONPATH is correct.
2. Am I correctly subscribing to the topic and getting the data? If not, what is the correct way?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243478/getting-%27rosgraph-resource-not-found%27-when-trying-to-get-turtlebot-local_plan?/) by [piraka9011](https://answers.ros.org/users/27954/piraka9011/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2016-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was running the script from my IDE directly.
To any one new with ROS: Do not do that...Instead build and run from the terminal using rosmake or catkin, then `rosrun [package name] [script]`

EDIT:
For completeness, see this [link](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs) that tells you how to setup your IDE for ROS.

---

Originally posted by [piraka9011](https://answers.ros.org/users/27954/piraka9011/) with karma: 32 on 2016-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0